# What is wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How can I finish Battle for Whiterun?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/295575/how-can-i-finish-battle-for-whiterun)

It seems that I "completed" battle for white run without doing anything. I just hop from places to places and suddenly the jarl has been replaced and all.

I didn't know that. So I asked around. Did I meet a bug or something? Why so many downvotes?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, the problem may not be with this question in particular. I believe the downvotes are due to your Skyrim questions, collectively.

As you've probably noticed, this isn't the first time one of your Skyrim questions has been negatively received. There's actually been a [meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12176/question-and-answer-hand-holding) raised about your Skyrim questions.

Many of your questions have garnered negative attention because of a few common factors:

1. You post a lot of questions in a single question's body.

   - You shouldn't do this as this makes your questions far too broad. You should limit yourself to a *single* question per question.
2. You have been posting *a lot* of questions about Skyrim in a very short time period.

   - It's not necessarily bad to post multiple questions about a game that you're playing, but multiple questions within a few hours is seen as a bit excessive.
   - Additionally, at least a few of these questions have answers on [UESP](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skyrim) or on the [Skyrim wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skyrim). When multiple questions by the same user have answers found in the same place relatively easily, it comes across to users as a lack of research done by the asker, which is a main reason for downvoting. ("This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.")
3. Many of your questions require editing by other users to make them more understandable.

   - The reason this gets frustrating is that there are a *lot* of posts that need to get edited, due to the volume of posts you've been making. This kind of goes in line with the first point.

My advice would be to do the following:

1. Ask one question at a time. This would make your questions much easier to read and answer. However, this doesn't mean you should post 7 separate questions all at once.
2. Slow down! Don't post so many questions all at once. It gives off the wrong impression, as you can see from the meta above. Had you asked your questions further apart than an hour or two, they may have been received more positively.

Comment: I understand. But that particular question is not problematic right? It has one question. It's not easy to research? Anyway thanks for feedback

Comment: @JimThio there was a bit at the end that a was kind of questionable, but other than that it was an OK question. See the linked meta. The fact that you asked a handful of questions in a short period of time irked some users, which likely led to downvotes, regardless of the quality of the question.

Comment: Is this behaviour (downvoting posts *because they are from a certain user*) traceable to certain users otherwise, then by the vote correction filter, which steps when the downvotes reach a critical mass from a single user?

Comment: @user3.14159265359 I wouldn't know, but I recall looking at JimThio's rep chart and seeing a Vote Correction in there. Also, there is another meta about serial voting over time and RavenDreamer said that they would still be able to tell.

Comment: @Vemonus I would guess the filter doesn't take action if many people downvote on the same user a few times, though.

Comment: @JimThio Hey Jim, I just wanted to add that I've spent some effort on answering a few of these, and have rarely downvoted them. I'm not upvoting either. Even to a pretty lax reviewer, there is some serious lack of research going on. I don't care if you post a million questions in an hour, as long as they make sense. What I *do* care about is not putting any effort into answering the question yourself.

Comment: This appears to be happening via the newly created Imbroglio tag, as well.  I bet the same thing might happen to those questions.  (Almost all questions created within minutes of each other by same user.)