# How frequently should I be asking questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

When I start playing a new and unfamiliar franchise I often have lots of questions, and I want to post them all at once. This occasionally ends up like [this Metro Exodus question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354547/how-does-radiation-work-in-metro-exodus), that was, at one point, eight questions rolled into one post.

Obviously, this is egregious scope and the number of questions has been reduced to a more reasonable size, and the post has been broken up. However the front page of Arqade now has three of my questions posted in less than an hour.

[image: Lots of Metro questions]

I try and take care of my formatting for these new posts and I believe that they're all adequate questions by their own merits. But I can't help but feel that I am posting too much, especially when I see the posts adjacent to each other.

When this happens should I wait to post more questions, even if they're well-written? Should I limit myself to one question per hour? Should I try and post the questions even if they do all show up on the front page at once?

I'm still a relatively new user to Arqade and I don't want to overstep my boundaries, but I also don't want to contain my interest in the game. What is the best way to approach this kind of curiosity?

Comment: Just another note, the fact that you posted in our meta and asked for clarity  already means you are more invested and caring about Arqade than most users. Welcome to Arqade and thanks for taking the time and learning in our meta!

Comment: I also love this sort of caring about adding to the site, and also I have to commend the asker for getting over 1,000 reputation in the process!! While I'm happy with my "shabby" 147. I do want 75 to be able to offer a bounty, and if not that, my next lower mark that I would like to at least get is 15 to be able to upvote (losing commenting privileges, while disallowing this comment, is not nearly as imprortant as upvoting what I would like!) I'm still pretty obviously "learning" still on Stack Exchange and do seek further knowledge about how this network of question and answer sites works.

Comment: In your own interest, you might want to space them out a bit, because some people might only be willing to write one good and long answer at once, not spend hours at a time on this site. But I don't know if that's actually how people behave, I bookmark questions that I want to answer in detail until later anyway.

Comment: In theory, people shouldn't be basing their votes on your questions on how often you ask questions, because they *should* be basing their votes on the quality of the question itself, irrespective of *who* asked it. Votes are supposed to be for content, not users. In practice people sometimes vote with their feelings rather than their heads, and that can mean that an otherwise fine question gets downvoted because they feel in some way slighted or annoyed by someone asking lots of questions in quick succession. It *shouldn't* happen, but the unfortunate reality is that it sometimes does.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can ask as often as you are allowed by [rate limiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/310045) (See Asking section). Some people might get a  little bit annoyed if you flood the front page with questions, but overall, as long as you make sure to ask well written questions (not too broad, clear question, etc) you will be fine. We can't answer questions or build a repository of knowledge if no one asks questions.

Also note, if people are target downvoting you for posting a lot of questions, it is quite likely that the votes will get reversed due to [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

Comment: So I can post as frequently as I want but some users might be bothered by it? Seems reasonable enough. I think I'll wait until other questions are posted before adding new questions myself

Comment: @PausePause also if your questions are related, the answer to one may help you figure out the answer to other questions you might have :)

Comment: +1 for "We can't answer questions or build a repository of knowledge if no one asks questions."

Comment: If someone has asked a ton of questions in quick succession then yeah, the serial voting stuff will kick in. But for 3 questions? Seems pretty unlikely

Answer (score 9):

As Dragonrage mentioned, there are hard limits in place in the form of rate limiting. They also mentioned people getting annoyed by multiple questions in a short period of time. I would like to focus on that part a bit.

We have had some issues in the past where users posted a lot of [really simple, often trivial questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12176/145980) in a relatively short amount of time (ranging between a couple hours to a couple days between questions). The case was brought to meta not solely because of the frequency of posting, but (in my opinion) because the questions were pretty low quality, which meant we as a community had extra work in trying to close duplicate and/or poor questions while trying to salvage the good parts of others.

Now let me provide a different example. Though I don't have a gold medal for it, I consider myself an expert on Terraria, at least the PC version of it. Any time a Terraria question pops up in the feed, I get excited because it's something I can share my knowledge for. If there's a new player who posts a bunch of good questions, I'd be ecstatic because then I would not only get to share knowledge, but possibly also do some additional research on new tricks or things I might not have known. The key words in that example, though, are "**good questions**". I don't want to answer another question about strategies to beat the Wall of Flesh, or how to build a valid house for NPCs, or any of the many other easily looked up trivia that exists on the (very detailed and thorough) game wiki. I suspect that a lot of other users feel the same way.

TL;DR: If you ask good questions that actually provoke some good answers, I don't think people will mind seeing multiple questions in a day. You'll typically only start getting flak if your questions are easily looked up elsewhere.