Is posting multiple questions back-to-back this way fine?
When I ask questions on the main site, I tend to ask multiple all at once, generally about the same game (or at least a small number of them). Heck, I have an entire note on the notes app dedicated to questions to ask on the Stack family.
By multiple, I mean, maybe, six or so. I try to keep them good quality, of course.
Here is todays batch of questions:

Rookie or Veteran difficulty
Beat Grafted Scion instead of dying
Return to Grafted Scion
CotL room modifiers
Inscryption energy system
Auto-build deck system

Is this fine?

Related: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13515/127901

It's generally fine to do this.  Other users in the past have done the same thing. If you don't abuse it (like bombard the site with 20+ questions all in rapid succession) it's typically fine.  Six questions isn't really an issue. The only thing it really does is skew the main questions page some since it'll have your questions all listed as the newest ones until someone else posts something, which really isn't all that long.
This reminds me of performing edits in a rapid fashion. In the past, users have made lots of edits to posts very quickly, causing the active questions tab to get updated with all the posts that were edited by said user(s). I am guilty of doing this myself a long time ago to the point where I received a warning from the mods (this was well before my time as a mod myself)!
So let's leave it at this:

It's fine to post questions like this, so long as it's not an extreme amount.
Keep in mind what it does to the questions page.
Try not to do this multiple times a day, and maybe consider spreading some of them out, or asking your question when it first comes to your mind instead!


Also consider that there's a daily rep cap of 200. You might miss out on rep if you have multiple popular questions/answers on the same day. On the flip side, there are badges for hitting the rep cap multiple times, so if you want to earn them, it's probably a good idea to post quickly

@Robotnik The Curious, Inquisitive, and Socratic badges ("Ask a well-received question on # separate days...") are also motivation to space out questions.

Sorry for the long gap in accepting the answer @TimmyJim. The reason I stick questions in a Note is generally because  I want to “optimise” the question, or because I’m not with my computer and don’t want to deal with typing on a phone.
